# Fetch call freezes

Tags: javascript, async-await, fetch, es6-promise

I am using fetch to read data from a API:

```
async _getDcnDetail(dcnId) {

         return await fetch(API_URL+'get_dcndetail', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Bearer '+ this.state.accessToken
            },                
            body: JSON.stringify({
                DcnId: dcnId
            })
        }).then(response => response.json());

    }
```

Then I call it:

```
async componentDidMount() {

   let response = await this._getDcnDetail(dcn.DcnId);
   console.log(response);

}
```

But it "waits" eternally, it is not resolving the promise.

As I understand fetch returns a promise which gets resolved by response.json(). I use "await" to wait the promise to be resolved, so not sure, what is wrong.

Comment: Have you checked the developer tools to see how the actual HTTP request went?

Comment: this code works fine. check if there is some problem with api or api url is correct?

Comment: If you want to help me in a related question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57662891/nodejs-querying-ms-sql-in-loop-freezes-response

Comment: Tip: You don't need async await since you are just returning result.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if some error occured on your POST request

```
async _getDcnDetail(dcnId) {

         return await fetch(API_URL+'get_dcndetail', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Bearer '+ this.state.accessToken
            },                
            body: JSON.stringify({
                DcnId: dcnId
            })
        }).then(response => response.json())
          .catch(err => alert("maybe some error occured"));
    }
```

Additionally, you should refactor this as,

```
async _getDcnDetail(dcnId) {

         try{
          const response = await fetch(API_URL+'get_dcndetail', {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization':'Bearer '+ this.state.accessToken
            },                
            body: JSON.stringify({
                DcnId: dcnId
            })
          });
          response = response.json();
          return response;
         } catch(e){
           console.log("error", e);
           throw err;
         }
    }
```

Do have a look on [promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function)